# Is there a oracle SQL query show me how many time I had Downtime in my Database through a year?

Tags: oracle

I want to see log for how often my oracle Database goes down ,so is there a SQL query can give me this info..

Comment: You need to start with defining downtime. When the database wasn't running or when it wasn't accessible from somewhere specific? This is most likely not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example for Oracle 11.2

Prepare

```
sqlplus / as sysdba 
CREATE VIEW X$_DBGALERTEXT AS SELECT * FROM X$DBGALERTEXT; 
GRANT SELECT ON X$_DBGALERTEXT TO <USERNAME>; 
CREATE SYNONYM <USERNAME>.X$DBGALERTEXT FOR SYS.X$_DBGALERTEXT;
```

select startup and shutdown time database.

```
select  to_char(originating_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' ), message_text 
from X$DBGALERTEXT
where  message_text like '%Starting ORACLE instance%' or
       message_text like '%Instance shutdown%'
```

Example output

```
2018-07-31 10:45    Starting ORACLE instance (normal)

2018-07-31 11:12    Instance shutdown complete

2018-07-31 11:13    Starting ORACLE instance (normal)

2019-01-25 10:16    Instance shutdown complete

2019-01-25 14:15    Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
```

Comment: That's a good start but if someone pulled the plug on the server the database wouldn't record the shutdown and you'd have to guess how long it was down.  Without a system like OEM, constantly monitoring the database, I'm not sure how accurately this question can be answered.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such info. To get those information you could create a shutdown / startup trigger and log the information in a new table.

For triggers see: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_trigger.htm#LNPLS01374

Database event: AFTER STARTUP / BEFORE SHUTDOWN